# Debian ARM and Brother MFCJ5320DW with CUPS

Tags: linux, debian, printing, network-printer, arm

I am trying to use a Brother MFCJ5320DW printer with Debian ARM, which is similar to:

- [Debian ARM and Brother DCP195C with CUPS](https://superuser.com/questions/781454/debian-arm-and-brother-dcp195c-with-cups)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191813/installing-brother-dcp-195c-on-cups
- https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3837/did-somebody-start-to-reverse-engineer-the-proprietary-linux-brother-cups-driver

I installed the ppd file and took the

```
/usr/lib/cups/filter/brother_lpdwrapper_mfcj5320dw
/opt/brother/Printers/mfcj5320dw/lpd/filtermfcj5320dw
```

files from the .deb file.  However, it appears that a binary file `/opt/brother/Printers/mfcj5320dw/cupswrapper/brcupsconfpt1` is still needed.  In the `brother_mfcj5320dw_GPL_source_3.0.1-1.tar.gz` file from Brother there is a source file which can be built to create

```
brother_mfcj5320dw_GPL_source_3.0.1-1/brcupsconfig/brcupsconfig
```

However, there is no documentation that suggests what to do with this file.

Has anyone solved this and managed to get the driver working on an ARM arch.?

Comment: Just managed to get through to a Brother technical agent.  They have no plans to build the closed source part of their printer driver for ARM architectures.  The technical agent mentioned that he had previously raised this with Brother management, but they classified it as a sales issue and the sales for ARM are not thought to be high enough.  While HP drivers are in general Linux repositories, they are not interested in allowing the Linux community to build Brother drivers.  Therefore, there are two options: (1) buy a i386 PC to act as the CUPS server for ARM clients or (2) reverse engineer.